# adding external code to Wordpress, MySQLi and head tags

Tags: wordpress, mysqli

I have a web page built separately to a wordpress site, and the wordpress site owner wants me to combine the content of the page into his wordpress site.

I am not used to building with wordpress, can anybody tell me if it is possible to add a link to an external database using MySQLi code and add css classes into the head tag?

I believe I can add the php MySQLi query into the body coding of the document can't I?

What is the correct way of doing this in the wordpress control panel?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your root folder with FTP access then you will see a file called `wp-config.php`

In that file you can edit the database connection en credentials.

Comment: If it does I surely will